# 64 bit integer bizarre results in the case of comparison

Tags: c++, aix

I am using `__int64` datatype on 64 bit AIX and I am getting bizarre results in the case of comparison with 0.

Code snippet :

```
__int64 indexExistingPart =  GetValue(); // GetValue always returns -1.

if (indexExistingPart < 0 )
{
    DoSomething(); //control never comes to this part of the code
}
```

I have also tried assigning 0 to another `__int64` variable and used in in the comparison. However, this also did not work:

```
__int64 indexExistingPart =  GetValue(); // GetValue always returns -1.

__int64 temp =0;

if (indexExistingPart < temp )
{
    DoSomething(); //control never comes to this part of the code
}
```

Why comparison operator is not working for 64 bit integers? Is there any workaround?

Comment: `__int64` is not a standard type - where and how is it defined ? Also, what is the return type of `GetValue()` ?

Comment: are you sure __int64 is not unsigned?

Comment: @Paul : return type of GetValue() is long. I am not getting any compilation error when i use __int64 on AIX.

Comment: @Johan __int64 is not unsigned . The same code works fine on Windows.

Comment: You haven't really answered the question - how and where is `__int64` defined ? Also what is `long` on your system - e.g. is it 4 bytes or 8 bytes ? Also are you building a 32 bit or a 64 bit executable ?

Comment: `__int64` is a Windows idiosyncrasy - you must have defined it somewhere for your AIX build - so how is it defined ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symptoms are consistent with `__int64` being a typedef for `unsigned long` in your project. (`__int64` is not a type provided by AIX, at least according to the IBM docs.) Try this instead:

```
#include <stdint.h> // or #include <sys/types.h>, or #include <inttypes.h>

int64_t indexExistingPart = GetValue();  // or "signed long indexExistingPart ..."

if (indexExistingPart < 0 )
{
    DoSomething();
}
```